# Why css selector expression with x:last-child doesn't work?

Tags: css, xml, css-selectors

I wrote a css selector that doesn't work. I want to understand why.
The following html:

```
<div class="container">
     <br>
     <br>
     <p id="copyright">...</p>
</div>
```

I wrote the expression:

```
div[class='container']>br:last-child
```

Because i read that:

> x:last-child selects all last-child x elements.

So why this expression returns nothing?

[image]

Comment: What element are you trying to match here? The second `br` or the last sibling `p` element?

Comment: the second br.. And i don't want an alternative way.. i want to understand why it doesn't work according to defenition

Comment: you need to use `:last-of-type`, `:last-child` expects that its the last element

Comment: @Sysix so the definition is wrong? I have added a screen shot

Comment: @Eitanos30 dont know where your docs are from. but look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: if br is the last-child of its container it will be selected, here the the last-child is a p , so no br:last-child to select because there is no last child that is a br tag. , ... br:last-of-type will select the last br found even if  it is not the last-child ..

Answer (score 1):

The last child of `div[class='container']` node is `<p id="copyright">...</p>` element.
To select last `br` child you need to use `:last-of-type`, something like this:

```
div[class='container']>br:last-of-type
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample `p` is the last child. Here it's colored in red:

```css
div[class='container'] p:last-child{
    color: red  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <br>
     <br>
     <p id="copyright">test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in the:
div[class='container'] p:last-child{
    color: red  
}

What is the meaning of **{color:red}**?
is this part of css selector?

Answer (score -1):

You likely aren't seeing any styles being applied because `br` tags are extremely limited in styling options. `br` tags simply generate a line break. So there's not really any content or dimension to them to style.

To show your selector is working, you can target the `p` tag instead of the `br` tag and you'll see the styles apply just fine. So change to `div[class='container']>p:last-child`. This is technically verbose as you could just as easily use this selector: `.container p:last-child` which is much more readable and clear. Just fyi.

I hope that gets you unstuck and moving towards a solution. Let me know if I've missed something.